# Ubuntu detects ACPI batteries on my desktop computer - thinks it is a laptop

Tags: laptop, battery, system, .desktop, acpi

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop computer with ASUS m5a97 Evo MoBo.
There is this battery indicator on my desktop. I already ran:

```
sudo laptop-detect -v
```

and it returned -> We're a laptop (ACPI batteries found)

Full system specifications:

- M5A97 EVO Asus MoBo
- Fx-8350 AMD CPU
- r9 280x GPU

Can it be related to MoBo features such as "AI Charger" etc.?
Or some power control settings MoBo provides via BIOS?
Can I override this laptop detection?

Comment: Do you have a UPS device attached somehow, possible via USB?

Answer (score 1):

you are a bit terse with your question. Do you have any adverse effects with your computer thinking it is a laptop?

As a quick and dirty solution, you could probably just deinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get purge laptop-detect
```

If you need it later again:

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-detect
```